# no data from ajax in cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am working in CakePHP to pass data via ajax. The data enter into the database successfully. This means the data pases from the view to the controller fine. However, it never populated the #target div. I have tried to even manually set the $data in the controller, but it still did not work. Here is my controller

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class GenreselectsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));

    // single search function
    public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('Notification');
        if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
            $this->autoRender = false;              
            $this->Notification->create(); 
            $this->Notification->save($this->request->data);

            $data = $this->request->data['Notification']['message'];            
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#genresearch').change(function() {           
            var selectedValue = $('#genresearch').val();

            var targeturl = '/genreselects/index/';

        $.ajax({        
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",           
            url: targeturl,
            async : true,
            data:{message:selectedValue},
            evalScripts: true,  
            complete: function(data) {
            //alert("hi neal"+selectedValue);
                $("#target").append(data);
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my view div

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

What iam i doing wrong

Comment: I can't see your action return data to the view, do you forget to set data with `$this->set($data);`?

Comment: Vini, i have. I tried the following and they did not work
$this->set('data', $data);
$this->set($data);

Comment: Did you checked in the browser console if your ajax call is returning some error?

Comment: Interesting. How do i do that?

Comment: I got it. there were no errors or warning

Answer (score 1):

You have neither echoed/printed the data nor set it to any view(since you have set $this->autoRender = FALSE;), that is why you are not getting any data being set to the target .

It should be like:

1) If setting AutoRender to FALSE;

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class GenreselectsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));

    // single search function
    public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('Notification');
        if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
            $this->autoRender = false;              
            $this->Notification->create(); 
            $this->Notification->save($this->request->data);

            $data = $this->request->data['Notification']['message'];   
            echo $data;//echo data so that it is received by your ajax call
            exit();
        }

    }

}
```

2) Setting content to view and rendering that as response in the target area:

```
   <?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

    class GenreselectsController extends AppController {

        public $components = array('RequestHandler');

        public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));

        // single search function
        public function index() {
        $this->loadModel('Notification');
            if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {        
                $this->Notification->create(); 
                $this->Notification->save($this->request->data);

                $data = $this->request->data['Notification']['message'];   
                $this->set(compact('data'));//here whole of the view with html will be returned as the response
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried. nothing. In my console. post, response, and json all have data. I am puzzled

Comment: Before moving ahead with it, you first print $this->request->data to see if desired data is there and the assign it to a variable before executing your save query.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your action has to echo something or your Ajax call fetches a blank page, which means no data. There are many ways to do that.

The most classical is using a view:

GenreselectsController:

```
public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('Notification');
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        //$this->autoRender = false;
        $this->Notification->create(); 
        if($this->Notification->save($this->request->data)){
            $message = $this->request->data['Notification']['message'];
        }
        else{
            $message = 'something bad happened';
        }
        $this->set(compact('message'));
    }
}
```

index.ctp

```
echo $message;
```

But you could for instance also return a JSON response:

GenreselectsController:

```
public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('Notification');
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $result = array();

        $this->Notification->create(); 
        if($this->Notification->save($this->request->data)){
            $result['success'] = $this->request->data['Notification']['message'];
        }
        else{
            $result['error'] = 'something bad happened';
        }

        $this->response->type('json');
        $this->response->body(json_encode($result));
    }
}
```

Or you could also use [JSON or XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had complete as the ajax function instead of success

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#genresearch').change(function() {           
            var selectedValue = $('#genresearch').val();

            var targeturl = '/genreselects/index/';

        $.ajax({        
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",           
            url: targeturl,
            async : true,
            data:{message:selectedValue},
            evalScripts: true,  
            success: function(data) {
            //alert("hi neal"+selectedValue);
                $("#target").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set $this->autoRender = false; so no view will be rendered
use this instead

```
$this->render('sometemplatefile', 'ajax');
```

this wil use the ajax layout

add this line to index()

```
 $this->set('message', $data);
```

create sometemplatefile.ctp 
 and put this code in

```
<?php echo $message?>
```